# Mysqli class not found. Using percona, php5-fpm, nginx, phalcon

Tags: php, class

```
Fatal error: Class 'TKStdlib\mysqli' not found in /var/www/tk-browser-app/application/library/tk-stdlib/DbAbstract.php on line 28
```

It sounds like I need mysqli installed. Yea I know, but it says it's installed when I do "php -m". It's in my php.ini file in php5-fpm as "extension=mysqli.so".

I find this guide http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php quite hard to follow. Where is the ./configure file supposed to be? Is that for php5-mysql or does it hold true for percona mysql also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set your script into a namespace and it's looking for the class in that namespace.

You can work around this by explicitly trying to reference the mysqli class as a global class:

```
$db = new \mysqli( ... );
```

For more on this, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php which says:

> Class names always resolve to the current namespace name.

Comment: I got "Unexpected character in input" changing from `mysqli` to `\mysqli`. This was on a fairly standard LAMP-based web hotel.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Namespaces were first introduced in PHP 5.3.0 (circa June 2009). If you're using an older version of PHP, it won't recognize the `\\` character.

Comment: You are right. Including "phpinfo();" reports *"PHP Version 5.2.17"*. What immediately comes to mind is "security vulnerabilities".

Comment: I later tried it on another fairly standard web hotel.  "phpinfo();" reported "PHP Version 5.6.18". Which seems current for the PHP 5 series, 2016-02-04(?) (http://php.net/downloads.php has "PHP 5.5", "PHP 5.6", and "PHP 7.0").

Comment: Perhaps you can include some of this information in your answer(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, the version of PHP that supports namespaces is noted in the link I gave in my answer.