# PHP Fatal error: class mysqli not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I try to connect using mysqli I get the following error below

Fatal error: class panda\mysqli not found and the line is where it says "new mysqli" when it connects

```
protected $db = null;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->connect();
}

public function connect()
{
    global $config;

    //it errors below here on the "new mysqli"
    $this->db = new mysqli($config['mysqli.host'], $config['mysqli.user'], $config['mysqli.pass'], $config['mysqli.name']);

    if ($this->db->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo 'Failed to connect to MySQLi: (';
        echo $db->connect_errno; 
        echo ') ';
        echo $db->connect_error;
        exit();
    }

    $db->set_charset("utf8");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are working with namespaces and PHP is - by default - trying to resolve `mysqli` relative from the `panda` namespace. A general rule is to prepend core-PHP classes with a `\` as they reside in the "[global space](http://php.net/namespaces.global)".

Comment: Related: [Bill Karwin's answer to *Mysqli class not found. Using percona, php5-fpm, nginx, phalcon*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434305/mysqli-class-not-found-using-percona-php5-fpm-nginx-phalcon/26434611#26434611) - this works from PHP 5.3.0 (circa June 2009). Yes, some web hotels still use versions of PHP that are older than 5.3.